# Is it possible to install iTunes on Windows 7 without Service Pack 1? For iPad Pro 10.5" support

Tags: itunes, ipad, windows

I'm considering buying iPad Pro 10.5" and meanwhile tried to download and install iTunes - main method of connecting it to the PC. My OS is Windows 7 pre-Service Pack 1. (I don't have MacOS) The installer of iTunes v12.7 is telling me I need to get SP1, which I don't want to do. Previous versions of iTunes I searched through on Apple site state: iPad Pro (9.7-inch) is not supported on Windows XP or Windows Vista.

Is it possible to have iTunes that can sync iPad Pro 10.5" models running on Windows 7 **without** Service Pack 1 installed?

Comment: Could I just point out that without SP1 you are about 150 security updates out of date, & may as well be running XP.

Comment: @Tetsujin well the thing is that it's 2GB ISO, so my assumption is that it will add "bulk" to the OS making it slower. Also, when there's so much new code, my assumption is there are at least 150 more new holes there. In my defense I have Windows Firewall that blocks almost everything native, except "Core Networking DNS". Do you think it's not good enough?

Comment: It's hardly "new code", it was released 6 years ago & has been obsolete since 2015, with only security updates until end of life in 2020. You are currently running a version no more secure than Windows XP & actually less secure than Vista SP2, as at least that had security updates until early this year. If you asked this question on that computer, then you are in no way secure.